# How can I control the type of object created based on the constructor arguments?

Tags: c#

So I have this setup

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public class SomeChildClass : SomeParentClass
    {

        ClassObject object;

        SomeChildClass(Object1 object1, etc)
        { object = object1 }
        SomeChildClass(Object2 object2, etc)
        { object = object2 } 

        method1()
        {
            object.doSomething();
        }
        .
        .
        .
        methodN()
        {
            object.doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

So there are many methods 1 - N that use object.DoSomething(), and I would like to find a solution to let them remain the same. So, is there a way I could define ClassObject to be either Object1 or Object2 outside of the constructors such that it allows me to keep my methods untouched?

Answer (score 0):

If `Object1` and `Object2` inherit from `ClassObject`, then you can use polymorphism and accept a `ClassObject` in a constructor.

Comment: If only this concept had a name!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use the usual polymorphism and inheritance (which requires ownership of all the types to put in place), you've got two choices:

- dispatch dynamically (by using `dynamic` in place of `ClassObject`)
- or create two wrapper classes that adapt Object1 and Object2 to a common interface

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `Abstract Factory` design pattern. 
What you need to do is: create a base class for your object classes:
`public abstract class BaseClass { }`

Then derive the classes you wish to create from base class while moving common attributes into the base class:

```
public class DerivedClassA : BaseClass { }
public class DerivedClassB : BaseClass { }
```

Now create an abstract factory class that takes an argument and then selects class based on it:

```
public static class AbstractFactory 
{
    public static BaseClass Create(string arg)
    {
        switch (arg)
        {
            case "A":
                return new DerivedClassA();
            case "B":
                return new DerivedClassB();
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException(nameof(arg));
         }
    }
}
```

This all works thanks to polymorphism. Polymorphism and abstract factory design pattern are widely known concepts, so you can easily find more information about them on the web.